# 'sed' command in unix

Tags: unix, sed

When I run the following:

```
$ echo "123 abc" | sed 's/[0-9]*/&/'
```

It outputs: `123 abc`

But when I run the following command:

```
echo "123 abc" | sed 's/[0-9]*/<&>/'
```

The output is: `<123> abc`

Why does it not output `<123 abc>`?

Comment: `[0-9]*` means any number of digits `0` through `9`, if you want alphanumeric with white space then use `[0-9a-z ]*`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression after your `sed` command is used for *Search & Replace*.

The `[0-9]*` part is the *Search* which describes which expression should be replaced by the notation of [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). When providing `[0-9]*` as a regex, you are asking `sed` to find any sequence of the digits 0 to 9 in the text and replace them with your replace expression.

The `<&>` part is the *Replace* which describes by which expression the former expression should be replaced. The `&` character is special, and allows you to refer to the the token that was found by your search regex.

In your first example you used `&` which keeps the numeric part found by the regex as is and in the later example you used `<&>` which wraps the numeric part that found by the regex in `<>`.

Comment: so, if [0-9]* finds any sequence of the digits 0 to 9 in the text and replace them, then why not my command : `echo "123 abc" | sed 's/[0-9]*/&/'`   outputs to : 123 ?

Comment: Because as I mentioned, it just replace it with itself (the non-numeric part doesn't change since it isn't part of your search regex)